# Perl redirect browser and keep processing

Tags: perl, redirect

This works fine (redirecting to a different domain):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl 
print "Location:http://AnyDomainBesidesMyOwn.com/\n\n"; 
close(STDOUT); close(STDIN); close(STDERR); 
[some long process]
```

But the following way stalls the browser, refusing to redirect until the long process is finished.  The only change from above is that I'm redirecting to another page on the same domain the script is running from.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl 
print "Location:http://MyOwnDomain.com/\n\n"; 
close(STDOUT); close(STDIN); close(STDERR); 
[some long process]
```

I know I can get this to work by forking a new process, but there's got to be a simpler way...right?

### UPDATE:  Here is the output I get from Live Headers in Firefox:

```
http://example.com/test3.cgi 

GET /test3.cgi HTTP/1.1 
Host: example.com 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0 
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
Connection: keep-alive 

HTTP/1.1 302 Found 
Date: Sun, 27 Jan 2013 23:31:49 GMT 
Server: Apache 
Location: http://example.com/ 
Vary: Accept-Encoding 
Content-Encoding: gzip 
Content-Length: 187 
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100 
Connection: Keep-Alive 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

---

### And then after it deigns to redirect:

```
http: //example.com/ [Have to include the space b/c stackoverflow limits the number of links I can include in a post]

GET / HTTP/1.1 
Host: example.com 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0 
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
Connection: keep-alive 

HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Date: Sun, 27 Jan 2013 23:31:54 GMT 
Server: Apache 
Accept-Ranges: bytes 
X-Mod-Pagespeed: 0.10.21.2-1381 [Same problem even on a domain w/o pagespeed installed]
Vary: Accept-Encoding 
Content-Encoding: gzip 
MS-Author-Via: DAV 
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache 
Content-Length: 12189 
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=99 
Connection: Keep-Alive 
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: Does teh browser receive the response? Does the browser send the request for the new page?

Comment: As I said, in both cases the browser redirects.  The only difference is that when redirecting to the same domain, the browser waits for [some long process] to finish before doing so.

Comment: That does not answer either of my questions. Redirecting is 1) getting a response telling it load another pages, 2) making a request for the other page, 3) receiving the other page. Repeating when it does (3) when I asked about (1) and (2) is not useful.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  What "gets a response"?  Who sends this response?  What is the response?  What is "it"?

Comment: Browser. You (but fixed and modified by the web server). "...\r\nLocation: http://...\r\n...".  Browser.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: You're asking a question about HTTP, and you don't know which request and response is being discussed!??!?!?!

Comment: I didn't think I was asking a question about "HTTP", I thought I was asking a question about Perl.  I know nothing about "HTTP", other than that it's the prefix of web addresses.  I don't understand your terminology.

Comment: Fine, tell me what call an HTTP request and an HTTP response, and I'll ask the question again with that terminology.

Comment: I don't understand you at all. I assume that an "HTTP request" is a request for a file from the server by a browser.  When you ask, "Does the browser send the request for a new page?", I did say explicitly in my original post that the browser stalls until the long process is finished, ergo, yes, the browser does send the request.  Since I was very clear, I assumed you were asking about something other than what I explained, but maybe you were really asking about what I pre-answered?  As for the "response", the requested page does indeed load, so yes, there's a response.

Comment: "I did say explicitly in my original post that the browser stalls until the long process is finished, ergo, yes" No, that only shows that it sent the original request, not the one your script instructs it to perform. Show the requests sent and the responses received already!

Comment: I posted what I think you're asking for.

Comment: To clarify, I meant I *just* posted what I think you were asking for, by editing the original question.  Does that help you?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have found a solution after some trial and error. The key is to use `fork()` and exit the parent process. Then close all the file handles in the child process:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Location: ../myHomePage.htm\n\n"; 

exit 0 if fork();
close(STDIN);
close(STDOUT);
close(STDERR);

# do some long process
open(SM, "| /usr/sbin/sendmail -ti -odq); 

⋮
```

In my case, the mail program was taking several seconds to accept the message and queue it. The webpage seemed very sluggish. After implementing the above, the redirect happenes instantly and several seconds later the message appeares in the mail log.

Answer (score -1):

You should exit after a redirect header sent out. If I am correct a space is needed after 'Location:'. You could use CGI redirect method to achive this.

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl
  print "Location: http://MyOwnDomain.com/\n\n"; 
  close(STDOUT); close(STDIN); close(STDERR); 
  exit 0;
```

Redirect with CGI: http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#GENERATING-A-REDIRECTION-HEADER

```
  use CGI; # load CGI routines
  $q = CGI->new; 
  print $q->redirect('http://somewhere.else/in/movie/land');
```

Comment: Adding a space after location doesn't help.  As for using exit, I think you're missing the point.  If I exit, then [some long process] doesn't execute.  I'm trying to redirect the user, and then continue processing.